# Populate variables based on met condition Ansible

Tags: ansible

Does anyone know a good article that explains how I would populate variables based on a condition being met?

Example:

```
- name: test
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
    group: "{{ item.group }}" 
    mode: 0755
  loop:
    - { path: "{{ file_location }}", owner: "{{ user }}", group: "{{ group }}" }
    - { path: "{{ configfile_path }}", owner: "{{ user }}", group: "{{ group }}"  }
```

Need to populate the first: `owner: "{{ user }}", group: "{{ group }}"` with a user and group named "X" when the machine is named XXX

Then populate the second: `owner: "{{ user }}", group: "{{ group }}"` with a user and group named "Y" when the machine is named YYY

I haven't tried anything yet because I am unsure how to tackle this, any pointers to documentation or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `when the machine is named XXX` -- this refer to the ansible host ?

Comment: @error404 correct

Comment: thanks just wanted to confirm. The below suggestion by Vladimir Botka is something should be preferred

Comment: @error404 thank you, I will give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Populate owner: "x" ... when the machine is named XXX. Then populate owner: "y" ... when the machine is named YYY."*

A: It's possible to use [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#working-with-inventory). For example in INI format

```
$ cat hosts
XXX owner='x' group='x'
YYY owner='y' group='y'
```

, or in YAML

```
$ cat hosts
---
  hosts:
    XXX:
      owner: 'x'
      group: 'x'
    YYY:
      owner: 'y'
      group: 'y'
```

, or it is possible to use [host_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-one-machine-host-variables)

```
$ tree host_vars
host_vars
├── XXX
├── YYY

$ cat host_vars/XXX
owner: 'x'
group: 'x'

$ cat host_vars/YYY
owner: 'y'
group: 'y'
```

See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#ansible-variable-precedence).

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `set_fact` module and `when` clauses.

[set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html):

> Synopsis
>
> - This module allows setting new variables.
> - Variables are set on a host-by-host basis just like facts discovered by the setup module.
> - These variables will be available to subsequent plays during an ansible-playbook run.
>
> ```
> - set_fact:
>     one_fact: something
>     other_fact: "{{ local_var * 2 }}"
>     another_fact: "{{ some_registered_var.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.some_fact') | list }}"
> ```

[when](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement):

> Sometimes you will want to skip a particular step on a particular host. This could be something as simple as not installing a certain package if the operating system is a particular version, or it could be something like performing some cleanup steps if a filesystem is getting full.
>
> This is easy to do in Ansible with the when clause, which contains a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces (see group_by – Create Ansible groups based on facts). It’s actually pretty simple:
>
> ```
> tasks:
>   - name: "shut down Debian flavored systems"
>     command: /sbin/shutdown -t now
>     when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"
> ```